# Is a certain rep required to be credited as a close voter?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I am aware that [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) states 15 rep required to flag posts.

But are flags from low-rep users (e.g. myself) ignored?

A few questions recently I flagged, and say 20-30 minutes later they were closed "by v, w, x, y, and z" - not my name, despite my giving the same reason (and obviously it wasn't closed at the time I flagged).

It's of no consequence whether my name's there or not of course, but what I'm asking is if my flags have no effect? Or perhaps it requires many more low-rep users to flag, but before that happens, a handful of high-rep users flag?

I cannot find details in the help centre of how non-moderator closing works.

Comment: You're flags are only taken as in indicator of "hey, this requires some attention". You are not attributed when the question is closed, because you did not take that action. But the flags are helpful in the sense that they let others know some action might be needed.

Comment: Oh I see! So there's a distinction between *flagging* and *voting to close*? That makes perfect sense, I just didn't realise it worked this way.

Comment: Note to self: "you're flags" ... really? ARGH. And to answer your comment (not you're), yep, they are distinct events.

Comment: I did notice you're error, but chose not too be "that guy" ;) I'll accept if you put that as an answer.

Comment: Gives you more incentive to get more rep! `:-)`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Casting votes to close (or to reopen for that matter) is a [3k rep privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Until then there are flags. A flag more or less indicates "there is an action that needs to be taken on this post" to those who have the required privileges to do so.

When a question is ultimately closed, this is attributed to those who actually closed it. You "merely" flagged it, so you don't get attribution for the closure, but the flag itself is most certainly helpful. And if you look at your flags, if it was helpful it will be marked as such.

Comment: Flags = "Somebody should take a look at this"

Comment: That's slightly incorrect, you only need 250 rep to vote for closing your own questions: [Privilige: See close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

Comment: What are those "flags" exactly? Flags to moderators or something else? Who can see them?

Comment: @Athari See [the Access Review Queues privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) and [the Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: Flags = Recommend Close = "Hey, I was the one who told you to do it". I see no reason to discredit flagging, it's the same as a CV (albeit just for human reviewers, not the system)